# Why isnt the app updating the textinput

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making an app to rename files that come from a scanner in a specific format.
The idea is to scan the directory and load a list of files, which are renamed according to the text in the textinput box. I've stripped down the app to come directly to the problem

```
import csv, os, datetime, string, shutil
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition

from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, DictProperty

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from functools import partial
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class TestScreen(Screen):
    def update_text(self, text):
        print(text)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    default_font_size = 15

    def build(self):
        compiled_kv_file = Builder.load_file("TestApp.kv")
        return compiled_kv_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Main loop")
    TestApp().run()
```

and the kv file is

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
transition:FadeTransition()
TestScreen:

<TestScreen>:
    name: "TestScreen"
    Button:
        text:"Test Screen"
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2,"y":0.8}
        font_size: 20
    TextInput:
        id: my_textinputa
        text:"File Screen"
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.4,"y":0.8}
        font_size: 20
        on_text:
            root.update_text(self.text)
    Label:
        size_hint: 1,0.5
        pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0}
        text: my_textinputa.text
        font_size: 20
```

I'm using windows 10 and eclipse with pydev, if thats relevant. The textinput returns the entered text to the .py file. But the textinput does not update the entered text. Furthermore, There seem to be two labels rather than 1.

My gut says that I'm somehow adding two sets of widgets on top of each other. Since only the top one is changed, the text does not change on the bottom one. The output in the console is correct. Yet the textinput box doesnt update itself.

Can someone suggest how to get the textinput to update correctly?

Comment: "But the textinput does not update the entered text. " Does not update where?

Comment: Run the app, a window opens up with a button and a textinput with "File Screen" on it. If I type the word " size", the on_text displays the correct output in the console: "File Screen ", "File Screen s", "File Screen si", etc.
The textinput widget on the app remains the same with "File Screen". It doesnt show the new characters typed.

Comment: Weird. If I try it with the code you provided, the TextInput is updated with the text I write (https://vid.me/EXF3).

Comment: Hmm thats funny. Here's how it comes on my pc : http://tinypic.com/r/2rf6gww/9

Comment: I suspect that you may be reading from two .kv files at the same time. You load `"TestApp.kv"`, but do you have by any chance, a `test.kv` file in the same directory?

Comment: There's no test.kv file. There were some backup copies. I've moved those to a subfolder and the error persists. But thanks, atleast you've confirmed that the code itself is correct.

Comment: What if you rename your kivy file to `test.kv` and replace the code of `build` to `def build(self): pass`?

Comment: This is awesome. Your suggestion worked like a charm. Any clue why? Is it that the app.run automatically looks for a kv file in the folder and loads its contents?

Comment: Yes, by default it will check for a .kv file matching the name of the App class instance. In addition it will also load any file you provided for `Builder`.  If, for some weird reason, two .kv files end up being loaded simultaneously, you get the issue you reported.

Comment: Thanks for the insight :) Post it as an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple .kv files defining the root widget can produce this issue. One solution would be to drop the `Builder.load_file("TestApp.kv")`

```
class TestApp(App):
    default_font_size = 15

    def build(self):
        pass
```

and rename the .kv file to the name of the `App` instance (`test.kv` in this case). In this way, kivy will only load one .kv file as the root widget.